# printing decimal to binary in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, decimal, parseint

I am having trouble with some code where the function is meant to convert the decimal numbers to binary from an array. I am using `parseInt` to do the conversions but it only prints the first number and more often prints `NaN`. My goal is to print all the binary equivalent of the decimal numbers on a html page.

Here is my code:

```
function decimal_table ()
  {
    // real_array stores decimal numbers.

    const real_array = [];
    const binary_array = [];

       for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
      {
        real_array.push(i);
        document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array.join(" ");
      }

       for (let b = 0; b <= 50; b++)
      {
        let calc = parseInt(real_array[b], 2);
        binary_array.push(calc);
        document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array.join(" ");
      }
  }
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
0 0000
1 0001
2 0010
3 0011
4 0100
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look to

```
parseInt(real_array[b], 2);
```

where you have a number which contains digits who are not parsable by having a radix of two.

As example take `2` and perform `parseInt(2, 2)`.

The result is `NaN`, because `2` is not a binary number, because binary numers have only digits of zero and one.

Beside that, it is the wrong direction, binary → decimal, but you need decimal → binary.

---

You need to take [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) with a base of two and pad the start with zeroes.

You could take a single loop and add the values to the array.

After the loop make the assignment to the elements.

```js
function decimal_table() {
    const real_array = [];
    const binary_array = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
        real_array.push(i);
        binary_array.push(i.toString(2).padStart(8, 0));
    }

    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = real_array.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("binaries").innerHTML = binary_array.join(" ");
}

decimal_table();
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
<div id="binaries"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toString()` method on the integer value with a radix (base) of 2 to get the binary representation.

Then you just pad the value.

```js
const pad = (n, padding) => (padding + n).substr(-padding.length)

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  console.log(pad(i, '  '), pad(i.toString(2), '0000'));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/string-format/0.5.0/string-format.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is a more advanced and self-documented version.

```js
const isFunction = (fn) => fn && {}.toString.call(fn) === '[object Function]'
const pad = (n, padding) => (padding + n).substr(-padding.length)
const range = (min, max, step) => {
  if (max === undefined) { max = min; min = 0 }
  if (step === undefined) { step = 1 }
  return new Array(max - min).fill(0).map((_, i) => min + (isFunction(step) ? step(i) : (i * step)))
}

let start = 0
let end = 7
let base = 2
let binStep = n => Math.pow(base, n)                   // 2^n
let maxVal  = binStep(end)                             // 2^7 = 128
let maxLen  = Math.floor(Math.log10(maxVal)) + 1       // 3 (unused)
let decPad  = maxVal.toString(10).replace(/\d/g, ' ')  // '   '
let binPad  = maxVal.toString(2).replace('1', '0')     // '00000000'

range(start, end + 1, binStep)
  .forEach(n => console.log(pad(n, decPad), pad(n.toString(2), binPad)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/string-format/0.5.0/string-format.min.js"></script>
```